# How do I do to make enhanced fonts and bold lines using gnuplot-py?

Tags: python-2.7, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot my data with labels (x and y) and font enhanced (bold) using gnuplot-py (on ubuntu python 2.7). What I did until now is:

```
g.xlabel("Wavelength (nm)")
g.ylabel("Elipicity (mdegree)")
g('set xrange [190:260]')
g('set xtics font ", 12"')
g("set terminal svg")
g.plot(d1)
```

I tried some internet protocols, but they did not work, as:

```
{/:Bold Bold}
```

or:

```
g.xlabel("Wavelength (nm) {/Times:Bold boldface-newfont}")
```

But none of them has worked. How do I do to make those changes using gnuplot-py?

Comment: `{/:Bold bold}` should work, at least if the terminal is in `enhanced` mode. You can request that explicitly by using `set terminal svg enhanced`. If that doesn't work then you have to figure out if the problem is gnuplot, gnuplot-py, or your image viewer. Type the following into gnuplot: `set term svg enhanced ; set output 'test.svg'; test; set output`, and open the resulting file `test.svg` in your viewer. Does the word **Bold** appear in bold?

Comment: @user8153 the problem was:

g("set terminal svg")

I changed it to "enhanced" and it worked out. Thanks!!